# Unable to upload files to server page

Tags: javascript, php, record

When pressing the upload link I am unable to retrieve the audio files on the server page. Any of your help will be greatly appreciated.
Here is the javascript code for upload:

```
//upload link
var upload = document.createElement('a');
upload.href="#";
upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload=function(e) {
          if(this.readyState == 4) {
              console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
          }
      };
      var fd=new FormData();
      fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
      xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
      xhr.send(fd);
});
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "));  //add a space in between
li.appendChild(upload);  //add the upload link to li
//add the li element to the ol
recordingsList.appendChild(li);
```

and here is the php code:

```
<?php
  print_r($_FILES); //this will print out the received name, temp name, type, size, etc.
  $size = $_FILES['audio_data']['size']; //the size in bytes
  $input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name']; //temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded file
  $output = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav"; //letting the client control the filename is a rather bad idea
  //move the file from temp name to local folder using $output name
  move_uploaded_file($input, $output)
?>
```

This type of error is occurring:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

specify a complete destination path for your output, not just a filename.

```
$output = "C:\temp\".$_FILES['audio_data']['name'].".wav";
```

Sometimes you also need forward slashes instead of backslashes. And be aware of security issues, the filename provided by the browser might contain baaad things.

Comment: Still having issues when tried with your destination path. any other suggestion?